# MacBook Pro trackpad: Must lift all fingers before tap

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

With the trackpad on my 2013 MacBook Pro using macOS, I use my middle finger for navigation and forefinger to tap. In this scenario, it is unnecessary for me to lift my middle finger to tap.

With Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome 3.38) installed on the same machine, I must lift all fingers to execute a tap.

a) What method(s) are available to allow Ubuntu to mimic macOS' behavior.

b) Is this typical Linux behavior or is this Trackpad-specific? (I don't have another trackpad to test)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, stock Gnome.